# RSpec tests break when validating embedded Mongoid models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, mongoid

I get this RSpec error when I try to embed one document in another. Sorry, I'm new to MongoDB. I'm used to sqlite3 and pg. I guess I just don't know how to test this sort of relation. Can someone help me out?

```
Player attributes validations should require a name
     Failure/Error: @hero = Player.create!(@attr)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `validated?' for #<Hash:0x007fb33f41dc88>
     # ./spec/models/player_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My validation is just a simple

```
validates_presence_of
```

Here's my [source code](https://github.com/protolif/game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your use of the class name Attribute - it's clashing with something else. Field also won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the [mongoid-rspec](https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec) gem on GitHub. It adds matchers to RSpec that seem to make more sense with Mongoid than the ones I'm used to. Check it out.